# How to disable the message 'The Marketplace has extensions ...' off

Tags: visual-studio-code

I receive again and again in VS code the message  'The Marketplace has extensions that can help with XXX'. In most cases the hint is far from helpful, but I cannot find a method to switch it off. It covers valuable messages appearing at the same location (I have the `explorer` panel all to the right).
Is there a switch somewhere and what is it? Thank you!

Comment: Did you try enabling the setting `Extensions: Ignore Recommendations`?

Comment: It's 2023, I already have `"extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true`, but when I open a `.tmpl` file for example, this box appears. I think this setting only ignores workspace recommendations based on the project, not recommendations for files we open. There's a button "Don't Show Again for '.tmpl' files", but this setting doesn't appear on `settings.json`. I think actually there's no way to disable this message globally and it's so annoying.

Comment: @thiagobraga I was encountering this as well. Turns out it's a bug. It's fixed for insiders but hasn't landed in stable yet. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/184706

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Enable the setting:

`Extensions: Ignore Recommendations`

> When enabled, the notifications for extension recommendations will not
> be shown.